# Magento 2 : How Can I Add custom.less File For Only Specific Page?

Tags: magento2, frontend, css, less, grunt

how can i add custom.less file for any specific page in child theme? means don't need genrate inside my custom css code in style-l.css or style-m.css and i have already 2 methods used.

**Method 1.**

create _custom.less and add css code

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_custom.less
```

_source.less (import in _cutom.less)

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_source.less

@import'_custom.less';
```

**Method 2.**

create "_custom.less" and "_extend.less" on same location

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_custom.less
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

import _custom.less in _extend.less

```
@import'_custom.less'
```

both of methods generate in style-l.css or style-m.css. but i want generate on browser css with specific css link.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your changes in your theme Less file then they will merge automatically into **styles-m.css** and **styles-l.css**

If you are generating browser CSS like custom.css so you can create a custom.css file at app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/

Or you can not create CSS files only use Less file for the specific page you can create _module.less file for the specific module for your requirement.

For example, create **module.less** at Vendor_Module/web/css/source/ path and put your style into this less file.

And if you want to view your created file on the browser then according to the custom.css module.less than use grunt and refer to the below link

[Compile LESS with Grunt](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/debug/#:%7E:text=CSS%20source%20maps%20solve%20this%20issue)

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. i will check  & let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, for example:

app/code/Vendor/Custom//view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Custom::css/custom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Custom/view/frontend/web/css/custom.less

```
   #maincontent {
        padding: 0;
   }
```

Comment: dear @Reshad, thanks for reply. i have use this method but grunt not compile on same time. when i remove pub/static folder and run static:content:deploy: command then generate css. i want when i save .less file generate css file on same time.